# Insert value with substitution variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

How can i use substitution variable in loop for inserting value in the below statement... loop limit is 5 times :

```
insert into emp
 (eid, ename, salary, hire_date, address)
values
 (&eid, '&ename', &salary, '&hire_date', '&address');
```

Comment: You can't prompt for substitution values is a loop. You can only loop in a PL/SQL block, and any substitutions are done before a block is executed. Do you have you to use a loop? Perhaps you can expand your question to explain what you're trying to do. Is the 5 fixed, for instance?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34789124/266304)?

Comment: Thank u so much for ur response Alex Poole
i need to use loop. please tell how can i use loop

Comment: Did you look at the question I linked to in my previous comment? Why do you need to use a loop? If you're prompting for the number of times to go round the loop, it sounds like the same problem.